# How to share a message on twitter on IOS 10 using ionic/cordova framework?

Tags: cordova, twitter, ionic-framework, ios10, android-sharing

I have created a cross platform application using ionic framework. In which it have social sharing features to share a message on facebook, twitter. This application is working fine on android OS with latest version and IOS 9. but on IOS 10, Twitter sharing is not working. I unable to find the reason, However, It seems that their may a bug in plugin which i used. 
Plugin link : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

I also noted that plugin is using this method to share a message.

```
    window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter(MSG_TWITTER_SHARE);
```